# Custom MKAnnotationView in MapKit like below picture

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit, android-mapview, mkannotationview

I want custom MkAnnotatioView when click pin on map like below picture...

[image]

Comment: sorry i is a new member so i could not upload image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let us know if it works:
http://blog.asolutions.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

There are lot resources related to create a custom callout annotation views. Do a search before ask question. If you are expecting someone will create and post the code for you, no one is going to do it.

[MultiRowCalloutAnnotationView for iOS](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/multirowcalloutannotationview)
[Creating Custom Call out View with button on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978598/creating-custom-call-out-view-with-button-on-it)
[how to add custom callout view in mapview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10394777/how-to-add-custom-callout-view-in-mapview)
[Customize the MKAnnotationView callout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018841/customize-the-mkannotationview-callout)